# TypeORM Migrations Hallucinating Changes Over and Over

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have a strange situation where TypeORM migrations constantly generate the same migration even after running.

Here is the migration which keeps being recreated even after it's successfully ran:

```
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner } from "typeorm";

export class Healthnutrition1708498657688 implements MigrationInterface {
    name = 'Healthnutrition1708498657688'

    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`social_chat_users\` DROP FOREIGN KEY \`fk_social_chat_users_chat_id\``);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`social_chat_users\` DROP FOREIGN KEY \`fk_social_chat_users_user_id\``);
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP INDEX \`idx_social_chat_users_chat_id\` ON \`social_chat_users\``);
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP INDEX \`idx_social_chat_users_user_id\` ON \`social_chat_users\``);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`social_chat_users\` DROP COLUMN \`last_read_at\``);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`social_chat_users\` ADD \`last_read_at\` datetime NULL`);
        await queryRunner.query(`CREATE INDEX \`idx_social_chat_users_chat_id\` ON \`social_chat_users\` (\`chat_id\`)`);
        await queryRunner.query(`CREATE INDEX \`idx_social_chat_users_user_id\` ON \`social_chat_users\` (\`user_id\`)`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`social_chat_users\` ADD CONSTRAINT \`fk_social_chat_users_chat_id\` FOREIGN KEY (\`chat_id\`) REFERENCES \`social_chat\`(\`chat_id\`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`social_chat_users\` ADD CONSTRAINT \`fk_social_chat_users_user_id\` FOREIGN KEY (\`user_id\`) REFERENCES \`users\`(\`user_id\`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`);
    }

    public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`social_chat_users\` DROP FOREIGN KEY \`fk_social_chat_users_user_id\``);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`social_chat_users\` DROP FOREIGN KEY \`fk_social_chat_users_chat_id\``);
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP INDEX \`idx_social_chat_users_user_id\` ON \`social_chat_users\``);
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP INDEX \`idx_social_chat_users_chat_id\` ON \`social_chat_users\``);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`social_chat_users\` DROP COLUMN \`last_read_at\``);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`social_chat_users\` ADD \`last_read_at\` datetime NULL`);
        await queryRunner.query(`CREATE INDEX \`idx_social_chat_users_user_id\` ON \`social_chat_users\` (\`user_id\`)`);
        await queryRunner.query(`CREATE INDEX \`idx_social_chat_users_chat_id\` ON \`social_chat_users\` (\`chat_id\`)`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`social_chat_users\` ADD CONSTRAINT \`fk_social_chat_users_user_id\` FOREIGN KEY (\`user_id\`) REFERENCES \`users\`(\`user_id\`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`social_chat_users\` ADD CONSTRAINT \`fk_social_chat_users_chat_id\` FOREIGN KEY (\`chat_id\`) REFERENCES \`social_chat\`(\`chat_id\`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`);
    }

}
```

The entity file:

```
@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
@Entity('social_chat_users')
export class ChatUsers {
    @PrimaryColumn({ name: 'chat_id' })
    chat_id!: number

    @ManyToOne(() => Chat)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'chat_id' })
    chat?: Chat

    @PrimaryColumn({ name: 'user_id' })
    user_id!: number

    @ManyToOne(() => User)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id' })
    user?: User

    @Column({ default: null, nullable: true })
    @IsDate()
    last_read_at?: Date

    constructor(partial: Partial<ChatUsers>) {
        Object.assign(this, partial)
    }
}
```

Run results:

```
query: SELECT VERSION() AS `version`
query: SELECT * FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'healthnutrition' AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'migrations'
query: SELECT * FROM `healthnutrition`.`migrations` `migrations` ORDER BY `id` DESC
4 migrations are already loaded in the database.
5 migrations were found in the source code.
Healthnutrition1708498611623 is the last executed migration. It was executed on Wed Feb 21 2024 06:56:51 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time).
1 migrations are new migrations must be executed.
query: START TRANSACTION
query: ALTER TABLE `social_chat_users` DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_social_chat_users_chat_id`
query: ALTER TABLE `social_chat_users` DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_social_chat_users_user_id`
query: DROP INDEX `idx_social_chat_users_chat_id` ON `social_chat_users`
query: DROP INDEX `idx_social_chat_users_user_id` ON `social_chat_users`
query: ALTER TABLE `social_chat_users` DROP COLUMN `last_read_at`
query: ALTER TABLE `social_chat_users` ADD `last_read_at` datetime NULL
query: CREATE INDEX `idx_social_chat_users_chat_id` ON `social_chat_users` (`chat_id`)
query: CREATE INDEX `idx_social_chat_users_user_id` ON `social_chat_users` (`user_id`)
query: ALTER TABLE `social_chat_users` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_social_chat_users_chat_id` FOREIGN KEY (`chat_id`) REFERENCES `social_chat`(`chat_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
query: ALTER TABLE `social_chat_users` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_social_chat_users_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users`(`user_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
query: INSERT INTO `healthnutrition`.`migrations`(`timestamp`, `name`) VALUES (?, ?) -- PARAMETERS: [1708498657688,"Healthnutrition1708498657688"]
Migration Healthnutrition1708498657688 has been  executed successfully.
query: COMMIT
```

But then it generates another file with the same commands with a new timestamp.

Any ideas as to why this is stuck in some kind of loop would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a mistake in the ormconfig.ts

are you sure that the migrations folder and the entitites folder is configured properly?

Edit after comment:
So I'm not an expert but looking at your code the relations between entities doesnt seem how you link relations. The 2nd parameter in the @oneToMany decorator should be the link to a property in the other entity.

For example

```
export class User{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @OneToMany(type => Project, project => project.user)
    projects: Project[];

}

export class Project{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.projects)
    user: User;

}
```

Comment: Sorry, no, I mean, each time I run the generate, it keeps populating the migration file with the same content, even though it runs successfully.

The only difference between this table and others in my DB is that it's referenced as a @ManyToMany in another entity:

https://github.com/juicyllama/framework/blob/main/backend/social/src/modules/chat/chat.entity.ts#L32-L44

Comment: Based on ur new info i have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Roy Stijsiger, I think you might be correct, the problem I have is my Users entity is abstracted away and cannot be updated.